# How do i use diffrent jdks for Netbeans and Eclips

Tags: java, netbeans

I have both Net-beans and eclipse IDEs installed in my laptop, But there is a per-devolved  system that want lower version of JDK. so I installed net-beans older version too. but then JDK does not support my eclipse version. can I use two JDK in once?? and what should I do for working in both IDE in different versions.

Comment: [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You need to give more information.  Normally IDE support older JDKs.  You can tell about the error and get some help.

Comment: Are you confusing the Java version used to run the IDE, and the version used to compile the projects? A modern IDE still supports older Java versions, but might need a new version to run it.

Comment: I don't know Eclipse, but for NetBeans this question is covered in the FAQ: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Configuration and the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#CHDCDBJH

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse / Net beans need JRE to run in first place. If the version of JRE you install is not supported by the version of Eclipse/Netbeans u have, then you have to get a compatible version of Eclipse/Netbeans that match your installed JRE. (Alternatively you can change the JRE version)

Now coming to JDK. You need JDK only to compile you code inside Eclipse/Netbeans. You can have any number of JDKs installed and you can configure 'per project'.

In Eclipse, this is how you configure the JDK for the project
**Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Libraries -> JRE System Library**

In the next screen you add the desired JDK from your system , by locating it in the file browser.

P.S : Havent used Netbeans, but sure it is supported